# MATLAB save variables to text files with '-ascii' format

Tags: matlab, save, ascii, eigen, eigenvector

I have the following code in MATLAB:

```
clear;clc;
k=load('OUTPUT_sub_1_stiffness.txt');
m=load('OUTPUT_sub_1_mass.txt');
[v_default,d_default]=eig(k,m);
v_kai=load('Eigenvector.txt');
d_kai=load('Eigenvalue.txt');
[v_qz,d_qz]=eig(k,m,'qz');
[v_chol,d_chol]=eig(k,m,'chol');
save('v_default.txt','v_default','-ascii');
save('d_default.txt','d_default','-ascii');
save('v_kai.txt','v_kai','-ascii');
save('d_kai.txt','d_kai','-ascii');
save('v_qz.txt','v_qz','-ascii');
save('d_qz.txt','d_qz','-ascii');
save('v_chol.txt','v_chol','-ascii');
save('d_chol.txt','d_chol','-ascii');
```

All the variable which start with `v` like `v_qz` are saved correctly as text files as shown below:

[image]

However, to my surprise, all the variable which start with `d` like `d_qz` can not be saved correctly, as shown below:

[image]

I wonder if anybody knows why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: just added this option `'-double'` and it got corrected, like below:

```
save('v_default.txt','v_default','-ascii','-double');
save('d_default.txt','d_default','-ascii','-double');
save('v_kai.txt','v_kai','-ascii','-double');
save('d_kai.txt','d_kai','-ascii','-double');
save('v_qz.txt','v_qz','-ascii','-double');
save('d_qz.txt','d_qz','-ascii','-double');
save('v_chol.txt','v_chol','-ascii','-double');
save('d_chol.txt','d_chol','-ascii','-double');
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the files exist before you save them?

And what is the format of the variable you are writing?

Comment: I added the `'-double'` option to save command and it got corrected!